# How to make mysql database works on a client computer (desktop appilcation)?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, desktop-application

I am making a JavaFX application (rental management software) and using MySQL database,

I was wondering how can I make my application works on my friend or client's PC since the database is on my PC? Is there is any way to configure the database on their PC without them doing all the installation processes of MySQL because they are not good with PC and it's not reliable to make the client set up the database I want to use a local database?

Comment: Look into SQLite and ship the DB with the program

Comment: Use embedded DB like SQLite, H2, HSQLDB etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Server versus embedded

There are two kinds of database engines:

- Those that run in their own process, as a separate app, accepting connections coming from any number of other apps on the same computer or over a network. This we call a **database server**. Postgres, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, etc run this way.
- Those that run within the process of an app, being started and stopped from that parent app, accepting connections only from within that parent app. This we call an **embedded database engine**. SQLite runs this way.

Some database products can run in either fashion. [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) is one such product.

Given your situation, and given that H2 is written in pure Java, I suggest replacing your use of MySQL with H2. Run H2 in embedded mode.

## Cloud database

Another option is for you to set up a database (MySQL or other) available to your users over the internets. You can run your own server. Or you can utilize any of several Database-as-a-Service (DBaaS) vendors such as Digital Ocean. This [“cloud database”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_database) approach may not be practical for desktop apps because of unreliable internet connections, security issues around database passwords, and the challenges of multi-tenancy.

## Repository design

By the way, you may want to learn about the [*Repository design*](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=repository+design+database&t=iphone&ia=web) approach in using interfaces and implementations as a [layer of abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer) between your app and your database. This makes switching out database engines easier.

For example, your repository interfaces would declare methods such as `fetchAllCustomers()` and `fetchCustomerForId( UUID id )`. One implementation of that interface might be built for MySQL while another implementation is built for H2. The code calling methods on your repository interface knows nothing about MySQL or H2.